# Exclude one element in .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to run through all textareas, excluding one whose id I have?

```
$("textarea").each(function (i, v) {
    // i could use an "if" inside here, but would rather adjust the selector
});
```

I have tried using `:not($('#mySpecialTextarea'))`, but could not get that to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jquery [**`.not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$("textarea").not('#mySpecialTextarea').each(function (i, v) {
    // your code
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6t9k6thk/)

You can also use [**`:not()`**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("textarea:not('#mySpecialTextarea')").each(function (i, v) {
    // your code
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ua2ohca/)

> The `.not()` method will end up providing you with more readable
>   selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a `:not()`
>   selector filter. In most cases, `.not()` is a better choice.